# "Not a valid bookmark" with DAO Recordset

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, dao

I'm in the process of converting an Access Data Project (ADP) into a standard ACCDB format with ODBC linked tables. In the ADP, I had overridden the Refresh button to return the user to the current record by using the following code:

```
Public Sub RibbonCmd_RefreshScreen(ctl As IRibbonControl, ByRef cancelDefault)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    cancelDefault = False

    DoCmd.Echo False

    Dim saveBookmark
    With Screen.ActiveForm
        saveBookmark = .Bookmark
        .Requery
        .Bookmark = saveBookmark
    End With

    'Success - cancel the default behavior
    cancelDefault = True

ExitHandler:
    DoCmd.Echo True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    cancelDefault = False
    Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

My understanding is that this should work just fine with DAO, but I get error 3159, `Not a valid bookmark.` I've also tried replacing `.Bookmark` with `.Recordset.Bookmark`, but that gave me the same result. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a requery of a form or a requery of a recordset will re-set and invalidate book marks.

So such book marks are no longer valid after a requery.

So the best approach here will depend on either

a) I simply want to re-display any changed records (and not move off current record).

b) I simply want to re-display any changed records AND ALSO display new records (the new records is the critical part).

If you just need a refresh, then you can use the appropriately called command refresh.

Eg:

```
Me.Refresh
```

Or in your case

```
Screen.ActiveForm.Refresh
```

So the above is ONE line of code and is ALL you need. The current record pointer for the form does NOT change when you use this command. All and any record changed will re-display for you.

Note that since you can behind the form button use:

```
Me.Refresh
```

Then LITTLE need is required to call a general routine as you have written.

However, if you need the form to "load" or display any new records added, then you DO have to use requery. In this case as noted book marks in this case all become invalid.

So, for code to requery, then we use the PK value (and hopefully you used the default pk of ID that been the default for 20 years). The code would then become:

```
Dim lngID         As Long

If IsNull(Me!ID) Then Exit Sub

lngID = Me!ID

Me.Requery

Me.Recordset.FindFirst "id = " & lngID
```

Now of course if the PK id is not the same for each form, then you most certainly could pass the NAME of the PK value to your "general" refresh routine. It would look like:

```
Public Sub MyRefresh(strPK As String)

   Dim lngID         As Long

   If IsNull(Me(strPK)) Then Exit Sub

   lngID = Me(strPK)

   Me.Requery

   Me.Recordset.FindFirst strPK & " = " & lngID

End Sub
```

The "hope" here is you actually really JUST need refresh, since as noted this is only one line of code, and better yet it does NOT move the record pointer.

Comment: Thanks, Albert. That seems to be the information I was missing -- a requery doesn't invalidate the bookmark in an ADP, and I didn't realize it would be different in an ACCDB. I had thought about using Refresh, but I'm afraid I do need requery. I was hoping there was a way to do this without changing my code to use IDs, but at least your answer explains why I have to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the forms Recordset.AbsolutePosition, and this works fine e.g. in the OnKeyDown exit of a field

```
Dim PrefilterPosition As Long

Private Sub ValnSubject_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

' Not F2 - exit
If KeyCode <> vbKeyF2 Then Exit Sub

'   Get the active control
Dim ActiveCtl As Control
Set ActiveCtl = Me.ActiveControl

ActiveControlName = ActiveCtl.Name

' Is the form's filter set?
If Me.Filter = "" Then

' NO: Apply the new filter
        ' Note the current position in the recordset
        PrefilterPosition = Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition

        ' Set the filter to the Active control's value
        Me.Filter = "[" & ActiveCtl.ControlSource & "]='" & ActiveCtl.Value & "'"
        Me.FilterOn = Me.Filter <> ""
        Me.Requery
Else

' YES: Clear the filter
        Me.Filter = ""
        Me.FilterOn = Me.Filter <> ""
        Me.Requery

        ' Align the recordset on the previously stored position
        Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition = PrefilterPosition

    End If

' Restore the cursor to where it came from
Me.Controls(ActiveControlName).SetFocus

Ex_it:

End Sub
```

---

For context: this code was from an idea for an 'Instant Filter', where you position the cursor on a field in a tab form, press F2, and then a filter is applied so you see only records with the selected field's value. Press F2 again and the filter is removed and the cursor goes back into the place it was when you hit F2 the first time. Bookmarks do not work here, as Albert says above.

Answer (score 0):

I use VB6 and Visual Data Manager in development. I have had the same problem. Most probably it arose when 2 users tried to update the same record in the same time. So some fields in the table are corrupted.
Here are the steps I used to solve the problem:
1- Copy the structure of the table (lets call it table1)to another table (lets call it table2).
2- Find the correpted record(s) in table1.
3- Transfer the data from table1 to table2 except the corrupted record(s)
4- Reenter the excluded record(s) to table2 again.
5- Rename table1 table3
6- Rename table2 table1

That's all folk

abdobox@yahoo.com